# Emberjs : Configure router to handle direct 'GET' requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How to configure router to handle xhr and direct requests to api.
Use Case : File Download
I have a `RESTAPI` with which i am trying to download a file using an `<a>` action link tag -> clicking on which resolves to a new Tab/Window with absolute url.
My webApp is serving at http://localhost:4200 `proxying request` to http://localhost:44226
When i try to hit the api to download the file using the url http://localhost:4200/api/download/files/1
I Get the error :
UnrecognizedURLError: /api/download/files/1

## Default Router

```
const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType // auto
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('logout');
});
export default Router;
```

Any pointers how to proceed/what to change.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use nginx in front of my Ember apps and API server. Which provides the the use of an expression to match URLs then - proxy to the API, or to the Ember app's routing. Here is an example https://gitlab.com/pixelhandler/xyz-conf/blob/master/qayaq.local to add a special url for downloads I'd add an addition rule via nginx.